# Will it be possible to run Java applets with Java JRE 11?

Tags: java

Support for Java Applets has been removed from just released Java JDK 11.
(See https://www.infoq.com/news/2018/09/java11-released for more information)

Does it means support of applets will be removed from Java JRE 11 as well ?
In other words, will it be possible to run Java applets with Java JRE 11 ?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what environment are you running applets in? No modern browser supports them anyway, so...?

Comment: the JDK used to provide the option to write applets, it's the browsers that provided the support to run them. seeing as, as @T.J.Crowder already mentioned, browsers won't allow the use of applets anymore ... why would you want to write applets?

Comment: Firefox has a kind of "LTS" version named "ESR" that still supports Java applets. Main purpose here is legacy system maintenance.

Comment: legacy system ... In Java 11?

Comment: @Stultuske Java 11 JRE (client side)

Comment: Even Firefox's legacy support ended last month, [according to their website](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/plug-in-support-has-been-dropped-other-than-flash/). Just FWIW.

Comment: @Stultuske - I can see wanting to keep Java up-to-date, even in a legacy system still using out-of-date technologies like applets. (Though I'd be worried about the degree of backward-compatibility required.)

Comment: I can't say more to you about the business side. I just can say we are dependent of deployed devices that embed a web interface using java applets. And in fact my question is general (i want to know. simply).

Comment: I don't think there is or will be JRE 11, period. There is Oracle's JDK 11 that you need to license if you want to use it in production. And there is OpenJDK with GPL license. No more JRE. I would love to be wrong, please, correct me, if you know more.

Comment: oh okay that make sense. i thought JRE were not released as of now. So JDK = JRE now ? same package ?

Answer (score 4):

As written here: [Java Client Roadmap Update](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf)

> During the past five years, most browser vendors have withdrawn
> support for plugins such as Flash, Silverlight, and Java in their
> products. Supporting Java Applets in browsers was only possible as
> long as browser vendors were committed to supporting standards based
> plugins. By late 2015, many browser vendors had either removed or
> announced timelines for the removal of standards-based plugin support,
> while some introduced proprietary browser-specific extension APIs.
> Consequently:
>
> - Existing Applet support in Java SE 8 will continue through March 2019, after    which it may be removed at any time.
> - Oracle announced in January 2016 that Applets would be deprecated in Java SE 9,    and removed from Java SE 11 (18.9).

The Alternative:
You will need to find potential Third Party Replacement. Import explicitly (eg using maven)