# Terminal Error with Java Runtime, can't recognize class file versions > 52.0

Tags: java, linux, terminal, runtime-environment

I'm trying to run this applet (compiled in a way that the class file version is 54.0) in Linux from Terminal, and although I installed the latest version of java, it's version it's stuck to 1.8.0_181, with its Java(TM) SE Runtime Enviroment (build 1.8.0_181-b13).

With some research I managed to find out that I need to set the JRE to java 10 to run it, but I never found the answer that I needed, the steps.
Many suggested Eclipse, but install it just to run an applet seems overkill to me, what can I do to set java up in a way that I can run this applet (whose class file is up to 54)?

p.s.
I'm gonna be honest what I need are the STEPS to get me there.

Answer (score 0):

The current latest version of Java is 14. If you have Java 1.8, it's not the latest version.

If the package repositories for your Linux distribution don't include the latest version of Java, you can install it from:

- https://adoptopenjdk.net/
- https://sdkman.io/

Comment: So when you go to your terminal and input: java -version, what's the text that appears on your screen?

Comment: The text that appears is the version of Java that you are running at that moment. I'm currently using Java 11 from the OpenJDK distribution, and the "java -version" command output shows `openjdk version "11.0.8"` for me. If I were to remove Java 11 and install Java 14 instead, I would see it tell me I have Java 14.

Comment: @StephenC I've removed the comment with incomplete wording. So far the OP's problem seems to be that the "latest version of Java" they have installed is 1.8 and not the actual latest version.

Comment: I followed a tutorial to install the JDK 11 version, but I installed the JDK 14 version, but at the end of it it's still stuck at version 1.8, from what  @Joni I should remove my current version of java(?), should I/ how do I do that? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72mz0-98vg8 (This is the tutorial btw)

Comment: Which Linux distribution (and distro version) are you using? Popular distributions are Ubuntu, Mint, Fedora, Debian. The way you uninstall Java, or make another version of Java the default, depends on the distribution you use.

Comment: Mine it's debian

Comment: ok. **step 1** Delete the oracle jdk the tutorial had you install manually **step-2** install Java 11 from debian packages: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk` **step-3** run `update-alternatives --config java` to choose which version of Java you want to use as the default

Comment: Thank you so much! I really mean it! That command solved all my problems. I didn't delete the oracle jdk from the tutorial though, I selected it and installed it and now the programs run no problem! Again, thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can:

- Run commands Java commands by giving the absolute path for the command.
- Change the `PATH` environment variable so that the directory containing the Java executables  is on the command path (in front of "/usr/bin" which is where the default Java commands will appear)
- Use the `alternatives` tools to change what (for example) `appletviewer` refers to.

Note that Java 10 is the *last version* that will support `appletviewer`.  Applets were deprecated in Java 8, and much of the applet support infrastructure was removed in Java 11; see [Will it be possible to run Java applets with Java JRE 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533768/will-it-be-possible-to-run-java-applets-with-java-jre-11).

Comment: Never heard of appletviewer, what's that and how can I access it?

Comment: Can't you just give me the terminal commands to run the proper version?

Comment: Where is your Java 10 installed?

Comment: So the commands "cd" or "cat" or "ls", are actually the commands' absolute paths?

Comment: No.  They are command names.  The absolute paths for "cat" and "ls" are "/bin/cat" and "/bin/ls".  (And "cd" is a shell built-in command, so it doesn't have a path at all.)  This is all basic Linux stuff.  You would do best finding and doing a Linux tutorial ...

Comment: Or if you couldn't be bothered, read this: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

Comment: I followed a pseudo linux tutorial, where they taught you the general stuff, that's why I miss the basics, but an entire Linux tutorial would be too much in my opinion, complementing it by asking questions seems more efficient to me, and today I learned this new basic thing thanks to you Stephen, thank you very much